# XML field Manipulation in an RDL report

Tags: xml, reporting-services, xquery, rdl

I'm rendering a report using an SSRS RDL (GreatestAxemenReport.rdl).  The RDL populates by calling a sproc (usp_SelectGreatestAxemenReportingData).

Well the key information I care about is in a field of XML type in my table (dbo.GreatestAxemenReportResults.xml_results)

Right now, I'm using xQuery to parse the XML field and split it into the report counts that I want to render on the RDL end.  This obviously gets cumbersome when you have to perform this action on a complex xml type, which is my case.

Does anyone know, is there a way to send the XML back to the RDL-end and have it know how to parse it intelligently, so I don't eat up DB server resources?

Thanks!